# Javascript: Trying to make images draggable and compare objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

stacksocial newbie here.

I'm working on a web project that's basically a puzzle game that teaches people how to configure the parts for a computer. Think pcpartpicker meets a puzzle but without the purchasing.

I've created several javascript objects with different elements that I plan on comparing via elements. (e.g Motherboard object has socket element and CPU has a socket element and these elements must match to continue).

When you click on the object in the nav. menu, an click event occurs where you the corresponding picture appears. I want to make that picture draggable. The end goal is to drag all the pictures together and compare the elements to make sure everything works out and if objects don't match an alert will tell the user that its wrong.

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ciddo/sgf50j96/9/

HTML+Javascript

```
     <title>Practice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src ="http://ie7-        js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta2)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    

      <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<header>
<script>
    var img1; //Motherboard
    var img2; //CPU
    var img3; //Memory
            var img4; //Case
            var img5; //Hard Drive
            var img6; //Power Supply       
</script>
<script>
    function preloader() {
        if (document.images) {
     img1 = new Image();
     img2 = new Image();
             img3 = new Image();
             img4 = new Image();
             img5 = new Image();
             img6 = new Image();

    img1.src = "http://i.imgur.com/u4cQogt.jpg"; // Motherboard
    img2.src = "http://i.imgur.com/snLSsMm.png"; // CPU
    img3.src = "http://i.imgur.com/L8jc43K.png?1"; // Memory
            img4.src = "http://i.imgur.com/oP6hsN0.jpg"; // Case
            img5.src = "http://i.imgur.com/WrFaslA.jpg"; // Hard Drive
            img6.src = "http://i.imgur.com/IMhS0uw.jpg";// Power Supply
        }
    }
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                    if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
        }
        func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
</script>
<script> 
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) { 
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}


</script>

<script>
```

//Need to call the folder containing images for all pc parts

```
//Variables that are used
var MoboSocket= ['LGA 1155','LGA 1150','LGA 1150','AM2','AM1','AM3'];
var MoboSize = ['ATX_Large','Micro-ATX_Medium','Mini-ITX_Small'];
var MoboMem = ['DDR','DDR2','DDR3','DDR4'];
var MoboPower = [25,50,75];
var intel = ['LGA 1155','LGA 1150','LGA 1150'];
var amd = ['AM2','AM1','AM3'];
var cpupower = [90,120,150,175,220];
var caseSize = ['Large','Medium','Small'];
var Memory = ['DDR','DDR2','DDR3','DDR4'];
var ram = [2,4,8,16];
var Power = [300,400,500,600,700];
var hddSize = [250,500,750,1000];

//Motherboards
var Motherboard = document.createElement("IMG");

var Motherboard1 = {
Socket:MoboSocket[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSocket.length))], 
Size:MoboSize[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSize.length))], 
RAM:MoboMem[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboMem.length))], 
Power:MoboPower[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboPower.length))]
}; 

var Motherboard2 = {
Socket:MoboSocket[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSocket.length))], 
Size:MoboSize[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSize.length))], 
RAM:MoboMem[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboMem.length))], 
Power:MoboPower[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboPower.length))]   
};
var Motherboard3 = {
Socket:MoboSocket[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSocket.length))], 
Size:MoboSize[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSize.length))], 
RAM:MoboMem[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboMem.length))], 
Power:MoboPower[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboPower.length))]   
};
var Motherboard4 = {
Socket:MoboSocket[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSocket.length))], 
Size:MoboSize[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboSize.length))], 
RAM:MoboMem[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboMem.length))], 
Power:MoboPower[Math.floor((Math.random()*MoboPower.length))]   
};    

    //CPU Parts    
var Intel_CPU = {
CPU:"Intel", 
Socket:intel[Math.floor((Math.random()*intel.length))],
Power:cpupower[Math.floor(Math.random()*cpupower.length)]
};


var AMD_CPU = {
CPU:"AMD", 
Socket:amd[Math.floor((Math.random()*amd.length))],
Power:cpupower[Math.floor(Math.random()*cpupower.length)]
};    

//Cases    
var Case1 = {
Size:caseSize[Math.floor((Math.random()*caseSize.length))]
};

var Case2 = {
Size:caseSize[Math.floor((Math.random()*caseSize.length))]
};

//Memory    
var Memory1 = {
Type:Memory[Math.floor((Math.random()*Memory.length))],
Size:ram[Math.floor((Math.random()*ram.length))]
};

var Memory2 = {
Type:Memory[Math.floor((Math.random()*Memory.length))],
Size:ram[Math.floor((Math.random()*ram.length))]
};
var Memory3 = {
Type:Memory[Math.floor((Math.random()*Memory.length))],
Size:ram[Math.floor((Math.random()*ram.length))]
};    

//Power Supply
var Power_Supply1 = {
Wattage:Power[Math.floor((Math.random()*Power.length))]
};
var Power_Supply2 = {
Wattage:Power[Math.floor((Math.random()*Power.length))]
};

//Hard Drives
var Hard_Drive1 = {
Size:hddSize[Math.floor(Math.random()*hddSize.length)]    
};
var Hard_Drive2 = {
Size:hddSize[Math.floor(Math.random()*hddSize.length)]    
};

//Generic Print Functions
function printPart(obj){
var str = "";
for (var x in obj){
    str +="<br>"+obj[x];
}
return str;
};

function printMobo(obj){
var str1 = "<br> Socket: "+obj.Socket;
var str2 = "<br> Size: "+obj.Size;
var str3 = "<br> RAM Type: "+obj.RAM;
var str4 = "<br>"+obj.Power;
var str5 = str1+str2+str3+str4;
return str5;
};

function printCPU(obj){
var str1 = "<br> Type: "+obj.CPU;
var str2 = "<br> Socket: "+obj.Socket;
var str4 = "<br>"+obj.Power;
var str5 = str1+str2+str4;
return str5;
};

</script>      


<script>
// Dragable moveable object code thingy
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName ("Motherboard")[0];
//ele.onmousedown = eleMouseDown;
```

ele.addEventListener ("mousedown" , eleMouseDown , false);

```
function eleMouseDown () {
stateMouseDown = true;
document.addEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
}

function eleMouseMove (ev) {
var pX = ev.pageX;
var pY = ev.pageY;
ele.style.left = pX + "px";
ele.style.top = pY + "px";
document.addEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}

function eleMouseUp () {
document.removeEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
document.removeEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}
</script>

<div id="jQuery">
<script>
    $(function(){

    });
</script>
</div>
</header> 


<body>

<div class="">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Motherboards</a>
    <ul> 
        <li id="Mobo1"><a href="#">Motherboard 1: 
                <script type="text/javascript">
              document.write(printMobo(Motherboard1));                  
                 </script>Watts
            </a>
        </li>

        <li id="Motherboard2"><a href="#">Motherboard 2: 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                     document.write(printMobo(Motherboard2));
                </script>Watts
            </a>
        </li>

        <li id="Motherboard3"><a href="#">Motherboard 3: 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                      document.write(printMobo(Motherboard3));
                </script>Watts
            </a>
        </li>

        <li id="Motherboard4"><a href="#">Motherboard 4: 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                      document.write(printMobo(Motherboard4));
                </script>Watts
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>    

<li><a href="#">CPUs</a>
              <ul> 
                  <li id="CPU1"><a href="#">CPU 1: <script        type="text/javascript">
                      document.write(printCPU(Intel_CPU));
                                  </script>Watts
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="CPU2"><a href="#">CPU 2: <script    type="text/javascript">
                      document.write(printCPU(AMD_CPU));
                                  </script>Watts
                      </a>
                  </li>                
              </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Memory</a>
                <ul> 
                    <li id="Memory1"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Memory1));
                                    </script>GBs
                        </a>
                    </li> 
                    <li id="Memory2"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Memory2));
                                    </script>GBs
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Memory3"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Memory3));
                                    </script>GBs
                        </a>
                    </li> 
                </ul>  

<li><a href="#">Power Supplies</a>
                <ul> 
                    <li id="PSU1"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Power_Supply1));
                                    </script>Watts
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="PSU2"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Power_Supply2));
                                    </script>Watts
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>                
            </li>

<li><a href="#">Cases</a>
                <ul> 
                    <li id="Case1"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Case1));
                                    </script>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Case2"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Case2));
                                    </script>
                        </a>
                    </li>                         
                </ul>                
            </li>

<li><a href="#">Hard Drives</a>
                <ul> 
                    <li id="HDD1"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Hard_Drive1));
                                    </script>GB
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="HDD2"><a href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                        document.write(printPart(Hard_Drive2));
                                    </script>GB
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>                
            </li>                                                   
</ul>
```

```
 <div>    
<script>

    document.getElementById("Mobo1").addEventListener("click", function() { 
        document.body.appendChild(img1);
    });
    document.getElementById("CPU1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.appendChild(img2);
    });
    document.getElementById("Memory1").addEventListener("click", function()     {
        document.body.appendChild(img3);
    });
    document.getElementById("PSU1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.appendChild(img6);
    });
    document.getElementById("Case1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.appendChild(img4);
    });
    document.getElementById("HDD1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.appendChild(img5);
    });
    document.getElementsById(img1).addEventListener("click", function() {
       alert("This Click worked"); 
    });
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body {
 font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 background: #e3e3e3;
 text-align: center;
}

 /* MENU */

#nav {
 background: #e5e5e5;
 float: left;
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-bottom: none;
}

#nav li a, #nav li {
 float: left;
}

#nav li {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
 padding: 1em 2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background: #292929;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-       stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
  border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-left: 1px solid #292929;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
 border-top: 1px solid #545454;
 }

 #nav li a:hover {
 background: #2a0d65;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11032e, #2a0d65);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#11032e),     to(#2a0d65));
 }


/* Submenu */

.hasChildren {
position: absolute;
width: 5px; height: 5px;
background: black;
right : 0;
bottom: 0;
}

 #nav li ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 100%;
 padding: 0; margin: 0;
 }

 #nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
 }

 #nav li ul li, #nav li ul li a {
 float: none;
 }

 #nav li ul li {
_display: inline; /* for IE6 */
}

#nav li ul li a {
 width: 150px;
 display: block;
}

/* SUBSUB Menu */

 #nav li ul li ul {
 display: none;
 }

 #nav li ul li:hover ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 }


 #nav li ul
```